# Merging two lists files based on unique column

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have two files, one is named NATLog with 3 columns and the other is Sourceports with 2 columns, Below is a sample of the NATLog file.

#### NATLog

```
14 172.18.2.12 445 
50 172.18.24.4 123
80 10.2.123.37 22
68 172.18.1.37 25
```

I want to match the last column of the NATLog file with the First Column of the Sourceports file and append the associated service to the NATLog file as a 4th column

#### Sourceports

```
445 SMB
123 Network Time Protocol (NTP)
22  SSH
25  SMTP(Insecure)
```

#### Desired Output

```
14 172.18.2.12 445 SMB 
50 172.18.24.4 123 Network Time Protocol (NTP)
80 10.2.123.37 22  SSH
68 172.18.1.37 25  SMTP(Insecure)
```

I am trying to learn AWK to accomplish this, but I am in need of some help, could you please assist me, thanks

Comment: I think your example is inappropriate. `paste NATLog Sourceports`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try awk,

```
$ awk ' NR==FNR {x=$1; $1="";a[x]=$0; next } { print $0, a[$3] } ' Sourceports NATLog
14 172.18.2.12 445   SMB
50 172.18.24.4 123  Network Time Protocol (NTP)
80 10.2.123.37 22  SSH
68 172.18.1.37 25  SMTP(Insecure)

$
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another in awk (well, two actually). This is for the perfect world:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{sub($NF,a[$NF])}1' source natlog
14 172.18.2.12 445 SMB 
50 172.18.24.4 123 Network Time Protocol (NTP)
80 10.2.123.37 22  SSH
68 172.18.1.37 25  SMTP(Insecure)
```

Explained (and a bit expanded for unperfect world):

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                          # processing the source file
#   gsub(/&/,"\\\\&")              # if & chars in the file, uncomment to escape them
    a[$1]=$0                       # hash to a, port is the key
    next
}
{                                  # process natlog file
    sub($NF,a[$NF])                # replace port field with entry from source file
#   sub($NF,(a[$NF]?a[$NF]:$NF))   # if gaps in source, use this instead of above
}1' source natlog
```

One possible output (shorter ip, `&` char in source and unmatched port 222):

```
14 1.18.2.12   445 SMB & 
50 172.18.24.4 123 Network Time Protocol (NTP)
80 10.2.123.37 222
68 172.18.1.37 25  SMTP(Insecure)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { key=$1; sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,""); map[key]=$0; next }
    { print $0, map[$3] }
' Sourceports NATLog
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is the output *formatting* shown with the protocol column appended in an aligned fashion, then `printf` instead of `print` provides the same fine-grained formatting control described in `man 3 printf` (for the most part). In your case you simply need to get the `length()` of the port number field and subtract that from the desired total field-width to add that many spaces after the record from `NATLog` before appending the saved protocol from `Sourceports`.

You could do that similar to the following where a total field-width of 4 is used as an example:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR {pcl[$1] = $2; next} {printf "%s%*s%s\n",$0,4-length($3)," ",pcl[$3]}
' Sourceports NATLog
```

**Output**

```
14 172.18.2.12 445 SMB
50 172.18.24.4 123 Network
80 10.2.123.37 22  SSH
68 172.18.1.37 25  SMTP(Insecure)
```

(**note:** your `Sourceports` cannot contain additional whitespace at the end of the records. If it does, then you will have to replace `$0` with individual `$1,$2,$3` and adjust the format-string accordingly)

There are usually many ways to accomplish the same thing in `awk` so you can tailor it to meet whatever need you have.

**Using `paste` and `awk`**

A shorter, but less efficient way would be to use both `paste` and `awk` to achieve the same thing. (basically just outputting the first two fields of `NATLog` and appending the contents of `Sourceports` with `paste`, e.g.

```
$ paste -d ' ' <(awk '{print $1, $2}' NATLog) Sourceports
14 172.18.2.12 445 SMB
50 172.18.24.4 123 Network Time Protocol (NTP)
80 10.2.123.37 22  SSH
68 172.18.1.37 25  SMTP(Insecure)
```

(but that would really defeat the purpose of learning `awk`)

Answer (score 0):

This is why linux has a bunch of tiny tools such as `cat`,`cut`,`paste` and in this case `join`.

```
join -1 3 -2 1 natlog source
```

Join works on files where the column you try to `join` on is sorted.

Sorted is actually a somewhat wrong wording here. It should be more like *equivalently ordered*. As you notice, both your files have the same input and output and the column you try to `join` on is equivalent. So `join` will work without a problem.

If both files are not equivalently orderdered, you could use sort on it beforehand:

```
join -1 3 -2 1 <(sort -k3 natlog) <(sort source)
```

or if you just want to stick to a single program, than `awk` is the way forward:

```
awk '(NR==FNR){k=$3; $3=""; a[k]=$0; next}{ print $0,a[$1] }' natlog source
```

but if `natlog` and `source` don't have the same number of lines and/or keys, then you get the common part as

```
awk '(NR==FNR){k=$3; $3=""; a[k]=$0; next}($1 in a){ print $0,a[$1] }' natlog source
```

Comment: @JamesBrown I was testing you