# compare different column of 2 different files and keep the orderin awk script

Tags: awk

I am trying to compare 2 different files ex:

file 1:

```
CALL AA
CALL AB
CALL AC
```

file 2:

```
00 AB n
01 AA o
02 AC o
```

the result i expect is
output:

```
AA 01 o
AB 00 n
AC 02 o
```

How can i get this without changing the order of the first file?(preferably in awk) Thank you in advance.

Comment: This might help: [Merging two lists files based on unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55109852/3776858)

Comment: thank you for the reply, but i am not trying to merge the columns here if you see my expected output its only selected columns from 2 files and also the main thing to consider here is to keep the order as it is in the first file.

Comment: From my point of view, what you're looking for is a merging of elements. That's why this is possible (with loss of order): `join -j 2 <(sort -k 2 file1) <(sort -k 2 file2) -o 2.1,1.2,2.3`

Comment: i tried this: awk ' NR==FNR {a[$2]= $2;next }$2 in a { $1 = $1 FS a[$3];print} ' file1  file2. This gives me output but not the order as in file1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from [example linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55332250/compare-different-column-of-2-different-files-and-keep-the-orderin-awk-script/55352519#comment97390216_55332250)

```
awk 'NR==FNR {x=$1; $1="";a[x]=$0; next} {print $0,a[$3]}' Sourceports NATLog
```

to

```
awk 'NR==FNR {x=$2; $2="";a[x]=$0; next} {print $2,a[$2]}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
AA 01  o
AB 00  n
AC 02  o
```

---

With optimization:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$2 FS $1 FS $3; next} {print a[$2]}' file2 file1
```

Output now without empty column:

```
AA 01 o
AB 00 n
AC 02 o
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: perfect! Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Yes, I did check and I accepted the answer but i am unfortunately not able to vote. :( I get this when I try to vote: 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.' Is there anything more to be done?